# how to save a image larger then in the phone

Tags: iphone, image, touch

I made an app following these instructions
http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024
And was great, but now, 
Now, I want to draw in another view at the same time (when the move begin, the line has to be drawn in both views), but different size (without scaling the one i'm touching)
is that possible?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would draw with OpenGL instead in that case, as you can add a larger view, and a camera which scrolls based on what the users actions are. You can find a great sample project to do this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html). In order to find more stuff about the camera, and making a larger view, you can look [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), or search in google for OpenGL iPhone tutorials. Hope that helps!